# meromorphic functions mapping unit circle to the real axis

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

Let $f$ be a meromorphic fuction (as the quotient of two entire functions).
 If $f$ has real values on the unit circle, then how are the zeros and the
 poles of $f$ located? What can you say about the general form of $f$ ?

Comment: Look at the periodic function $f(e^{iz})$ and apply the Schwarz reflection principle? You'd also need to worry about not having a limit point at $\Im(z)=-\infty$.

Comment: Ah! I was looking at old comprehensive exams for an exam coming up and I don't know the Schwarz Reflection Principle (yet). Thanks.